# Balancing bandwidth allocation for nfsd

Tags: optimization, nfs

I am using NFS shares to transfer image files using clonezilla onto multiple lab machines, I am currently only imaging one or two machines at a time as a testing protocol but whenever I run more than one instance of imaging at the same time the first instance gains around 1.6 GB/min of bandwidth whereas the second gets a fraction of this speed, seriously slowing down the process. Is there anyway of balancing the bandwidth allocated to each machine so that once a second NFS share is mounted they get around the same transfer rate instead of one getting most of it?

Sorry if this is badly worded, not really sure how to describe this process...

Comment: Other image cloning solutions use freshly imaged nodes to further distribute images in a tree-like fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this at your NFS server by bonding the connection (see: [Link Aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)). Use multiple links on the server side to make more bandwidth available for clients. The details of the implementation depend on what's actually running NFS, but that's somewhere to start.